# Implement heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (indexPath.row == 10) {
        tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath // make the last row height = 100;
    }

    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 10) return 100.0;
    return 44.0;
}
```